# iOS 7 Make Control Center hard to open like fullscreen mode while still showing status bar

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

My app is a productivity app that shows the status bar. Just for navigation we use swipe up gestures that often come up from the bottom edge of the screen, often toggling Control Center accidentally.

I want to make scrolling less annoying for my users by utilizing including the fullscreen toggles that game apps have for Control Center and Notification Center that mandate two swipes to active them.

[image]

Can you please tell me how to get this two-swipe-up sort of Control Center toggling in my app while still showing the status bar?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. The system will only show this tab when the status bar is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I think there have been some changes in iOS 7.1:

For example you can access notific/control-center in safari fullscreen (landscape) directly without this clip.

So probably there's a command to enable/disable the two-swipe-up control center, has someone an idea what we're looking for?

Comment: Safari is an Apple system application, it has access to private API not available for use on the appstore.

Comment: so do you think that this is really a private API? I know that Apple has access to APIs we don't have (officially), but don't you think it would make sense to make this api public?

Comment: It is private, yes. What they do in the Safari case is move the status bar window. (You can see for yourself - you can attach to MobileSafari in the simulator with Xcode and debug.) You do not have access to the status bar window with public API.

Answer (score 0):

Put these keys in info.plist file

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>

<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

The two stage swipe up behavior is only enabled when the application hides the status bar.  If you look in the Info.plist of the GLPain sample, it has included the UIStatusBarHidden key with a value of TRUE.  It also includes the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance with a value of FALSE, which is necessary for the UIStatusBarHidden to have any effect in iOS 7 and above.  If you include both of these keys/values in your application's Info.plist file, your should see the behavior you expect.